# How to set up a Rail 6 app without sprockets, yarn, vue or react

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to set up a rails app without `sprockets`, `vuejs`, `react` or `yarn`. Happy to retain `webpacker` though with transpiling using babel. Also, npm. What do I need to do following the following command?

```
$ rails new myapp --skip-sprockets --skip-yarn --database=postgresql
```

Wondering why there is both sprockets and webpacker in rails 6 now. Backward compatibility?

Comment: You seem to be good already IMHO. vuejs and react are installed only when specifying `--webpack=react` for example, and you're not.
Sprockets would be required in the case you would go with ActiveAdmin for example, many libraries have not switched to webpack yet.

Comment: Webpacker is coupled to yarn. Some folks have found some workarounds that include overriding selected rake commands.